# Module python-twitter (github) giving error "No Module named cmdline" from shell

Tags: python, shell, twitter, github, module

I've just installed the latest python twitter build ( https://github.com/bear/python-twitter ) and I'm receiving the below error. I get it when I try to use "twitter" from the shell...the "pip install python-twitter" worked fine, except it uses outdated api. This one seemed it might be updated, but throws the below error.

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/twitter", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('twitter==1.12.1', 'console_scripts', 'twitter')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 353, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2302, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2029, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named cmdline
```

I'm having a hard time drilling down to what is causing this. Any thoughts?

In response to comments, I'm posting the output for each step, to see why the error remains:

## 1

```
pip uninstall twitter
```

response:

```
leo@production:~$ sudo pip uninstall twitter
Uninstalling twitter:
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twitter-1.12.1-py2.7.egg
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled twitter
```

## 2

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twitter-1.10.2-py2.7.egg
```

(silent)

## 3

```
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/t/twitter/twitter-1.12.1.tar.gz
tar -xzf twitter*.tar.gz
cd twitter*
```

(successful)

## 3

```
sudo python setup.py build; sudo python setup.py install
```

Response:

```
p.py install
running build
running build_py
running egg_info
writing twitter.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to twitter.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to twitter.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to twitter.egg-info/entry_points.txt
reading manifest file 'twitter.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'twitter.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing twitter.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to twitter.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to twitter.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to twitter.egg-info/entry_points.txt
reading manifest file 'twitter.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'twitter.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/twitter/follow.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/twitter/api.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/twitter/twitter_globals.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/twitter/ansi.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/twitter/stream.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/twitter/ircbot.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/twitter/timezones.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/twitter/auth.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/twitter/archiver.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/twitter/stream_example.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/twitter/cmdline.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/twitter/util.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/twitter/logger.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/twitter/oauth2.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/twitter/oauth.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/twitter/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/twitter/oauth_dance.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter/follow.py to follow.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter/api.py to api.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter/twitter_globals.py to twitter_globals.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter/ansi.py to ansi.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter/stream.py to stream.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter/ircbot.py to ircbot.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter/timezones.py to timezones.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter/auth.py to auth.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter/archiver.py to archiver.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter/stream_example.py to stream_example.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter/cmdline.py to cmdline.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter/util.py to util.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter/logger.py to logger.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter/oauth2.py to oauth2.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter/oauth.py to oauth.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/twitter/oauth_dance.py to oauth_dance.pyc
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying twitter.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying twitter.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying twitter.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying twitter.egg-info/entry_points.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying twitter.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying twitter.egg-info/zip-safe -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
creating 'dist/twitter-1.12.1-py2.7.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing twitter-1.12.1-py2.7.egg
Copying twitter-1.12.1-py2.7.egg to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Adding twitter 1.12.1 to easy-install.pth file
Installing twitter-log script to /usr/local/bin
Installing twitter script to /usr/local/bin
Installing twitterbot script to /usr/local/bin
Installing twitter-follow script to /usr/local/bin
Installing twitter-stream-example script to /usr/local/bin
Installing twitter-archiver script to /usr/local/bin

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twitter-1.12.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for twitter==1.12.1
Finished processing dependencies for twitter==1.12.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this error a while back.  What I did is completely remove Python Twitter Tools with:

```
    pip uninstall twitter
    sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twitter-1.10.2-py2.7.egg
```

Then I reinstalled it by using:

```
    wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/t/twitter/twitter-1.12.1.tar.gz
    tar -xzf twitter*.tar.gz
    cd twitter*
    sudo python setup.py build; sudo python setup.py install
```

Now it should work.

Comment: Silly question ... where is the <.egg file>

Comment: `sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twitter-1.10.2-py2.7.egg`

Comment: Perhaps I've made some progress. For some odd reason, I do not have a "/site-packages/" directory in python2.7 (ubuntu 13.10). This may be part of the problem?

Comment: Try just doing the `pip uninstall twitter` then wget it, and install it again.

Comment: Yes, I've done that several times, the error keeps coming up. I'm going to post the output for each step -- I suspect there is a deeper problem. You can edit out the noise after :D

Comment: Perhaps the posted results might help determine why the particularly named error is there.

Comment: Fixed it -- thanks  for your help, since your comment inspired the final answer, I gave you the checkmark :D

Answer (score 2):

Found it! Thanks to @RydallCooper I was put on the proper trail :D

I had two packages apparently...

I had to uninstall them both:

```
pip uninstall twitter
```

and then:

```
pip uninstall python-twitter
```

Now the error is gone :D

Answer (score 0):

(A few years on!) the solution may be to check the versions

E.g. if you're using a Python 3 shell, you may need to use `pip3 install twitter` rather than just `pip install twitter`